# Does await completely block the thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

When we use `await` in the code, generally the awaiters capture the context and use that as callback when the awaited task completed successfully. But, since `await` is generally a No-Op (No Operation), does it make the underlying thread not being reusable until execution of the awaited task completes?

For Example:

```cs
public async Task MethodAAsync()
{
    // Execute some logic
    var test = await MethodB();
    // Execute remaining logic
}
```

Here, since I need the result back to proceed further, I need to await on that. But, since we are awaiting, does it block the underlying thread resulting thread not being used to execute any tasks?

Comment: My understanding is Task will continue as No.Op but multiple tasks can be executed in the underlying thread and hence it is not blocked.

Comment: If it did block, what good would the feature be? It would be equivalent to calling .Result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But, since await is generally a No-Op (No Operation), does it make the
> underlying thread not being reusable until execution of awaited task
> completes?

I'm not sure where you got this information from, but `await` is *certainly not a No-Op*. Calling `await` on a `Task`, for example, will invoke a logical call to `Task.GetAwaiter`, where the `TaskAwaiter` has to implement `INotifyCompletion` or `ICriticalNotifyCompletion` interface, which tells the compiler how to invoke the continuation (everything after the first `await`).

The complete structure of `async-await` transforms your call to a state-machine such that when the state-machine hits the first `await`, it will first check to see if the called method completed, and if not will register the continuation and return from that method call. Later, once that method completes, it will re-enter the state-machine in order to complete the method. And that is logically how you see the line after `await` being hit.

> But, since we are awaiting, does it block the underlying thread
> resulting thread not being used to execute any tasks?

No, creating an entire mechanism only to block the calling thread would be useless. `async-await` allows you to actually yield the calling thread back to the caller which allows it to continue execution on that same thread, while the runtime takes care of queuing and invoking the completion.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no, it doesn't block your thread.

More info: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Answer (score -2):

The thread has a local queue of Tasks. Once it hits an `await` it will pick up another Task from it's queue (assuming all methods up it's stack are `awaited`). If the queue is empty, it will try to get a Task from the global queue, and if it's empty too - the thread will try to get a Task from another thread's own local queue. In a simple program, where all threads might get "out of Tasks" - the thread will remain idle until one of the Tasks returns.