# I'm trying to understand async

Tags: asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await

I thought I understood how to use async, but I'm looking at some code, and I don't get it.

```
Stream stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(path);
```

What is the point of using an async method if you are just going to turn around and await it immediately?
Doesn't await effectively make this code synchronous?
What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895695/why-do-i-need-to-await-an-async-function-when-it-is-not-supposedly-returning-a-p

This should provide a detailed answer

Comment: You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705703/does-await-completely-block-the-thread There are different implementation strategies for implementing async/await (promises, coroutines, state machines, maybe others?), but in C#, a state-machine transformation is done. In short, using `await` behaves like a special kind of `return` which ends the execution of your function, but remembers how to come back and continue where it left off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your next line depends on the `stream` to do something, there's no magic that can work around that. That's a serial data dependency. Cause must come before effect, and your code must wait for the `stream` to be available before it can do something with it.

Asynchrony can't change that, but it doesn't even aim to.

What it *does* do is free up the thread to go do other things while you wait. By using `await`, you're registering this "logical thread of execution" (idk the correct term in the C#/CLR world) as being dependant on the outcome of `GetStreamAsync`. Your code will stop executing, but will pick right back up automatically when the result is available. In between those two events, the thread would have been free to execute other stuff, until they too reach an `await`.